# Why do I get RENEGOTIATING when sending RCPT TO to my SMTP service behind an AWS NLB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, aws-fargate, aws-nlb

I'm using ECS Fargate via a network load balancer (NLB) using TLS 1.2 to host an SMTP service that uses the standard SMTP interrupts to communicate with the client.

I'm testing the service via `openssl`.

This works fine both locally and both on Fargate:

```
$openssl s_client -connect xxx.com:443
HELO
250 OK
MAIL FROM:AAA@BB.COM
250 OK
QUIT
250 OK
```

However, the Fargate service works fine for all SMTP commands on NLB/Fargate except any command that starts with the character `R` e.g. `RCPT TO:`.

I get `RENEGOTIATING` followed by `connection close`, which does not happen locally.

```
$openssl s_client -connect mynlbhost.tampabayclosure.com:443
HELO
250 Hello
MAIL FROM:AA@BB.com
250 OK
RCPT TO:BB@CC.com
RENEGOTIATING
write:errno=54
```

I tried `openssl s_client -connect host:port -no_renegotiation` & `openssl s_client -connect host:port -no_renegotiation -tls1_2` none of which worked.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these solutions will work:

1. Use TLS v1.3
2. Use `openssl s_client -quiet` to suppress the interactive interpretation of `R` and `Q` characters
3. Use `rcpt to:` (which you can since SMTP commands are case-insensitive according to [RFC 5321](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-2.4))

---

> What is the issue?

This behaviour is related to [`openssl s_client`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-s_client.html):

> When used interactively (which means neither -quiet nor -ign_eof have been given), and neither of -adv or -nocommands are given then "Basic" command mode is entered. In this mode certain commands are recognized which perform special operations. **These commands are a letter which must appear at the start of a line**.

> R
>
> **Renegotiate the SSL session** (**TLSv1.2 and below** only).

This is why you’re seeing the `RENEGOTIATING` message followed by a connection close when you input `RCPT TO:` or any other command *starting* with `R`.

Note that the position of the `R` is important - that's why you didn't get this issue when you used `MAIL FROM:` even though it contains an `R`.

---

> does not happen locally

This is most likely because you're not using SSL locally.

Comment: `openssl s_client -quiet` did the trick. Thank you